# Not clickable Share buttons

Tags: css, button, html

I'm working on this site http://fireworkslove.com and I add a "hello bar" with share buttons. But I don't know why these are not clickable, something in the "hello bar" is wrong.

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index` to class `hellobar`

```
.hellobar {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #CCC;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #FDD5D3;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Also the button to open/close the Hello Bar have a little bug ¿any idea? I took the code from here http://designitcodeit.com/item/hello-bar

Comment: Sorry Sowmya I don't understand, I mean the bug when you click on the arrow of the Hello Bar. It moves wierd. See the original site to see it working ok.

Comment: couldn't find in your site. check with the altered css and values should be changed proportionately

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code in css file:

> input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {padding: 0;}

I don't think it will make any difference but doesn't hurt to try. That code is to try to make the slide up and down transition smoother.